# Sort a dictionary (Python 3.7 and later) based on values (strings/list) in the order that they appear in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am given a sequence—`test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`—in a dictionary form:

`{"animal": "fox", "pace": "quick", "action": "jumps"}`,

that needs to be sorted by `value` based on where those values appear in the aforementioned sequence, i.e., the following form:

`{"pace": "quick", "animal": "fox" ,"action": "jumps"}`

The way that I am looking at this currently is through the use of `sorted()` method, but what would the `key` parameter be?

In my current code, I am sorting the `dict` using:

`{k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: test.split().index(item[1]))}`

*Is there a more efficient way to do this?*

In a related question, if the original dictionary contained values in the form of `sets`, i.e., `{"animals" : ("fox", "dog"), "animal": ("fox")}`, would it be possible to sort it still based on the elements—`{"animal": ("fox"), "animals": ("fox", "dog")}`?

Comment: I'd suggest giving it a go, and then post your code here if there's still a problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @j1-lee fixed it (order in dict), sequence is a string ("the quick brown fox...").

Comment: Ask 1 question. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419644/15497888).

Comment: As phillipxy said, you should ask one question per question. Your related question can wait until next time. Solve this problem first. (BTW, those are tuples, not sets).

Answer (score 3):

First observation: We want to use the values in order to figure out something about the key-value pairs (specifically, to sort them). That suggests that the dictionary is the wrong way around; we should invert it first:

```
test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
info = {"animal": "fox", "pace": "quick", "action": "jumps"}
info_r = {v:k for k, v in info.items()}
```

Second observation: now we want to sort the keys of this inverted dict according to their position in the original sentence; but we could just as easily iterate over *the sentence* and check (with a now O(1) dict lookup) whether they are in the dict. As we go along, we can re-reverse the pairs and build the dict again in a dict comprehension:

```
{info_r[w]:w for w in test.split() if w in info_r}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was saying. I would have put the timeit line in for comparison, since rv.kvetch already did the setup, and it is the fastest on this data set. Although not much difference because the data set is so small; growth doesn't really factor in yet.

Comment: I see, I get it now. It was kind of hard for me personally to understand with words, but seeing it in action paints a better picture for sure. I was able to time it briefly and it is indeed faster overall.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very close to what I would say is an "efficient" approach - though the jury's still out on whether it's the *most* efficient approach possible.

```py
test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

d = {"animal": "fox", "pace": "quick", "action": "jumps"}

# split into words once, rather than on each `lambda` call
res = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x, words=test.split(): words.index(x[1])))

print(res)
# {"pace": "quick", "animal": "fox" ,"action": "jumps"}
```

A likely faster approach could be to build a word to index mapping beforehand, then simply do a `dict` lookup on each iteration.

```py
seen_pos = {word: idx for idx, word in enumerate(test.split())}
res = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: seen_pos[x[1]]))
```

When in doubt, always `timeit`:

```py
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('{k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item, words=test.split(): test.split().index(item[1]))}',
             globals=globals()))  # 1.233
print(timeit('dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: test.split().index(x[1])))',
             globals=globals()))  # 1.012
print(timeit('dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: words.index(x[1])))',
             setup='words=test.split()',
             globals=globals()))  # 0.534
print(timeit('dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: c[x[1]]))',
             setup='c = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(test.split())}',
             globals=globals()))  # 0.442
```

Comment: The indexmap takes it from quadratic to n log n (sorting). However, if we make a reverse word map, we can just iterate over the original list, which is by definition, already sorted according to itself.

Comment: While that is O(n) I'm not sure how growth effects it, since the map to be sorted is potentially much smaller than the total number of words in the sentence.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Building the index map requires iterating over the words in the sentence anyway, so your approach sounds likely to be faster in general. I took the liberty of writing it up as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was just saying if the map is reliably much smaller than the sentence, we can basically ignore the cost of sorting it. But doing it right would handle the worst case much better.